# Install package with at least the specified version

Tags: fedora, dnf

After a HDD failure I managed to save the list of installed packages on my Fedora 23 box. I have already reinstalled the base system and now want to restore the old packages. I tried

```
xargs sudo dnf install < packagelist
```

where `packagelist` is the output of `rpm -qa`, but it fails on several points (no match for packages; I guess the version number formatting is not how `dnf` wants it.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: If you think version numbers are a problem, have you tried removing them?  That would be the first obvious place I'd start.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the command reference](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#specifying-packages-label)  I'd try feeding `dnf` the output of

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n"
```

The default query format is

```
%{NAME}-%{VERSION}.%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n
```

Note the dash versus dot between the version and release.

...and now that I've tested it there is a bug in the documentation. :) It should be a dot.

The best option may be to remove the version, release, and arch completely:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}\m"
```

Comment: That sounds great and next time I will do my “backup” this way. However, this doesn’t solve the problem: I already have a file with the packages listed, which I need to pass to rpm.

Comment: The problem is that it is impossible to strip off the version from the packagelist. `awk -F. '{ print $1 }' < packagelist | sed 's/-[-0-9]*$//'` is a staring point.

Answer (score 1):

Use **DNF** with **cat**

```
dnf install $(cat packagelist)
```

Comment: That’s basically the same as I used, except I feed the package list via `xargs` so the argument list doesn’t get too long.